# WCF service to get Files from a SharePoint 2010 library fails for huge files when the client is running on a remote box

Tags: wcf, sharepoint-2010

I have a WCF webservice hosted on IIS7.0. I am using this service to  query a document library on SharePoint 2010 to get the Items from the library using SP object model.
Client creates a service reference of this service and tries to get the items from the SP 2010 Library.
This works fine for smaller files, but when the client tries to receive huge files, my service times out.
If the client is running on the same box where the WCF service is hosted, then there is no issue accessing the files of any size, but when the client is run from any other remote boxes, the service times out.

I am using WSHttpBinding, with MTOM message encoding

Please let me know what I am missing

Comment: It's probably something in your configuration.  Please share both the client and server pertinent details.

Answer (score 1):

Few things to look at:
Enable [tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx) on server side to see exactly what caused the connection to time out. See [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wcf/thread/d05dccbc-3cce-4c77-8193-12626c14594b/) link for more info.

Default time out for an http request in SP 2010 is 120 seconds. See [this link](http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/archive/2010/09/04/how-to-increase-the-timeout-for-a-sharepoint-2010-website.aspx) on how to increase the default timeout.I do not suspect this as a problem, but do this only if everything else does not work.